# how to remove stop words from a text file?

Tags: python

review_words is another text file that I have wherein I'll need to remove stopwords from.

```
def remove_stopwords(word_list):
    review_words = []
    for word in word_list:
        if word not in stopwords.word('english'):
            return review_words
            print(review_words)
```

However, when I run it in powershell, it still doesn't remove the stopwords from review_words.

Can somebody please enlighten me!!
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You never loaded in or wrote to a text file in this script. Your `print` statement also will never run because it occurs after the `return` statement. You also never modify the `review_words` list which you probably are wanting to do.

Comment: @amanda-teo, welcome to SO. Since you're still pretty new, and your question isn't well formulated, I would suggest taking a look at [how to ask a good question ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You know what you need to do; you need to call the function. Even if you don't know what the correct way to do that is, you should go ahead and *try* something. *Anything*. Then see what happens and learn from it. And if you've already realized that the function isn't being called, you should include that information in your question. We can't read your mind. I'm sure that if you show us an attempt of you calling that function and asking a specific question like *"Why did `review_words` not change even though I called `remove_stopwords`?"*, you'll get an answer within 5 minutes.